# Can NumPy calculate the % change the way it is shown in multiple instrument charts?

Tags: programming, data, market-data, historical-data, visualization

I have closing prices for multiple equities in NumPy arrays (or a pandas timeseries DataFrame).

I like to calculate the % change numbers for the closing prices in the DataFrame the way it is shown in mainstream charting platforms like the one below:

[image]

Is there any common NumPy method to calculate % change prices based on $ prices when we compare multiple instruments?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63781913/4350650

Comment: Thank you @Mayeulsgc. It helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - just divide (`.div()`) the values in each series by the starting value in that series and subtract 1. The actual syntax will depend on how your data is organized (e.g. row/column order).